# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP:

Tags: jsp, rest, jboss

Estoy intentando crear un API Rest para devolver un json desde SQL Server a desplegar en un JBoss 6.0.0 (tiene que ser éste) en NetBeans; lo he creado generando unas *entidades* desde la BBDD y *sessions* sobre las mismas, aplicando dos clases java para configurar y generar la consulta tal como expone este [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7fUDeiCPBo). El problema es que al intentar desplegarla en local (no la he subido al servidor), sin errores de compilación de ningún tipo en ningún momento, me da el error del título del mensaje y la verdad es que no sé muy bien por dónde empezar a revisar.

Por lo que he leído por ahí, es incluso más relevante otro error, que aparece como "The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files", pero tampoco soy muy capaz de entender las respuestas.

El stacktrace es el de abajo:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP: 

Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 1 en el fichero java generado
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:360)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:338)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:325)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:607)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Y el index.jsp, que no he modificado del que genera, es;

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

He intentado importar el .war a Eclipse pero me da el mismo error.

Cualquier ayuda en este sentido sería bien recibida. Gracias de antemano. 
Saludos

Comment: No pongas capturas de pantalla, edita tu pregunta y cambia la imagen por el texto del *stacktrace*. Y estaría bien que añadieras el código del JSP

Comment: Gracias por el aviso, lo edito como me indicas. Saludos.

Comment: Mucho mejor, muchas gracias. Procuro aprendérmelo.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java estás usando? Lo digo porque parece que ese problema puede ser causado por ser un contenedor viejo (JBoss 6.0) con Java 8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963248/the-type-java-io-objectinputstream-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenc

Comment: La última, la 1.8.0_151, la he actualizado e incluso he cambiado las variables de entorno con la ruta de ésta, pero nada. Incluso he cambiado las versiones de Tomcat también y en algunas (la 7 y la 9) ni siquiera reconoce la página, no lanza el rest.

Comment: Si vas a usar JBoss 6.0, te recomiendo que pruebes con Java 7, no es bueno mezclar productos muy antiguos (JBoss 6 es de 2010) con las últimas versiones del JRE

Comment: En principio debo utilizar JBoss 6.0.0, el sistema es de 2012 y no hay otra, no quieren hacer cambios; he pensado en publicar el rest incluso en otro servidor y hacer las consultas desde allí, por todos los problemas que me está dando pero tampoco lo aceptan por temas de seguridad. Voy a intentar lo que me dices, emplear versiones más antiguas del JDK a ver si con eso se resuelve. Te lo agradezco de verás.

Comment: Muy típico... usar un sistema que ya no tiene mantenimiento y luego quejarse de la seguridad

Comment: Teniendo los dos servidores, de datos y de aplicaciones, abiertos en la wifi sin más, poca importancia se le puede dar a esas quejas.